# Наследование и __init__ в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование, методы

недавно начал изучать Python3, дошел до ООП и заметил странность, автор курса говорит, что нужно обязательно указывать в методе **init**, вызов метода **init** класса предка:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def drive(self):
        print(self.name + ' is driving')

class Truck(Car):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Car.__init__(self,name)

man_truck = Truck('Man')
man_truck.drive()
```

Но в следующей лекции уже не вызывает метод **init** класса предка:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def speak(self):
        print(self.name + ' is saying woof')


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def speak(self):
        print(self.name + ' is saying meow')


spike = Dog('Spike')
tom = Cat('Tom')

spike.speak()
tom.speak()
```

Но при этом все работает и особой разницы нету. Хотелось бы узнать почему так происходит и на что это влияет? (P.S. Заранее благодарю за внимание и ответ :3)

Comment: Также было бы интересно узнать, этот случай во множетсвенном наследовании*

Comment: Это необязательно. Но может быть полезно, когда родительский `__init__` содержит много нужной Вам логики (соблюдается DRY).

Answer (score 2):

В примерах разная логика.

В первом примере я бы пивал `super(Truck, self).__init__(name)`

Во втором примере объект `self.name` класса `Animal` вообще не используется.
И наследуясь от `Animal` все равно что от `object`

Попробуйте и обратите внимание на принты, который я вставил.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(f'!!! {name}')             # <<<-----<
        self.name = name
        
    def drive(self):
        print(self.name + ' is driving')

class Truck(Car):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Truck, self).__init__(name)

man_truck = Truck('Man')
man_truck.drive()

print('---------------\n')


class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(f'??? {name}')             # <<<-----<
        self.name = name


class Dog(object):                       # Animal
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def speak(self):
        print(self.name + ' is saying woof')


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def speak(self):
        print(self.name + ' is saying meow')


spike = Dog('Spike')
tom = Cat('Tom')

spike.speak()
tom.speak()
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ!

Comment: 'пивал' это что? )

Answer (score 0):

> Это необязательно. Но может быть полезно, когда родительский **init** содержит много нужной Вам логики (соблюдается DRY). – nomnoms12 9 минут назад

*Благодарю пользователя @nomnoms12 за ответ*